# How to transfer Thunderbird calendar from Windows 10 to Ubuntu

Tags: thunderbird

New to Ubuntu so I apologize if this one's been asked and answered. TBird works fine but I need to import the calendar (tasks and events) from my old Windows account.  I found the windows folders but don't know where Ubuntu needs the calendar to be.

Comment: Looked good, thank you.  Alas, no go. "Import failed unexpectedly".  I'm now looking for the "Error Console".

Comment: No luck.  Maybe if I had done that first it might have worked.  Is there a way to clear the app and restart fresh?